# Getting the length of a formatted string from wsprintf

Tags: c, wchar-t

When using standard `char*` strings, the `snprintf` and `vsnprintf` functions will return the length of the output string, even if that string was truncated due to overflow.* It seems like the ISO C committee didn't like this functionality when they added `swprintf` and `vswprintf`, which return -1 on overflow.

Does anyone know of a function that will provide this length? I don't know the size of the potential strings. I might be asking too much, but.. I'd rather not:

- allocate a huge static temp buffer

  iteratively allocate and free memory until i've found a size that fits

  add an additional library dependency

  write my own format string parser

**I realize MSVC doesn't do this, and instead provides the `scprintf` and `vscprintf` functions, but I'm looking for other compilers, mainly GCC.*

Comment: I never knew about MSVC's `scprintf()` set of functions. Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My best suggestion to you would be not to use `wchar_t` strings at all, especially if you're not writing Windows-oriented code. In case that's not an option, here are some other ideas:

1. If your format string does not contain non-ASCII characters itself, what about first calling `vsnprintf` with the same set of arguments to get the length in bytes, then use that as a safe upper bound for the length in `wchar_t` characters (if there are few or non-ASCII characters, the bound will be tight).
2. If you're okay with introducing a dependency on a POSIX function (which is likely to be added to C1x), use `open_wmemstream` and `fwprintf`.
3. Just iterate allocating larger buffers, but do it smart: increase the size geometrically at each step, e.g. 127, 255, 511, 1023, 2047, ... I like this pattern better than whole powers of 2 because it's easy to avoid dangerous case where allocation might succeed for SIZE_MAX/2+1 but then wrap to 0 at the next iteration.

Comment: Sadly, I'm not writing from scratch - I'm fixing/extending an existing codebase. I didn't know about open_wmemstream.. that could be a good way to go.

Comment: Well note that, unless the distribution of string sizes you're dealing with is very spread out, you'll likely get the best performance with approach 3 and choosing an initial size that's at least as long as "most" strings you deal with. I would guess 127 would suffice for that.

Answer (score 0):

This returns the buffer size for wide character strings:

```
vswprintf(nullptr, -1, aFormat, argPtr);
```

Comment: First, in C there isn't a predefined `nullptr`; that is a property of C++11.  Secondly, the standard requires a non-null pointer for `vswprintf()` to work correctly.  Thirdly, the `-1` argument is going to be interpreted as `size_t`, and is therefore enormous.  While this means that you won't run out of space (so you won't get a negative response from `vswprintf()`), you still have problems with writing through a null pointer.